# Pandas: Merge contents of a dataframe into a single column (as a list of dict / json)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-manipulation

I want to introduce the contents of one df to another but as a list based on ID. I know to merge based on ID but I do not want duplicate rows for ID in the new dataframe. How do I get this done?

```
data1 = {'ID': ['AB01','AB02'], 
    'Name': ["toyota", "honda"],
    'Age':[21,22]
   }
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data1)
data2 = {'ID': ['AB01','AB01','AB03','AB03'], 
    'Type': ["C",np.nan,"X","S"],
    'Score':[87,98,45,82]
   }
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data2)
```

[image: Input dataframes]

The result should look like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `dict` on the rows of `df2` by [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), then group by `ID` and aggregate the dict of same `ID` into list by [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html).

Then, merge with `df1` with [`.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) by left join with `ID` as matching keys, as follows:

```
df2_info = (df2.apply(dict, axis=1)
               .groupby(df2['ID'])
               .agg(list)
               .reset_index(name='Info')
           )

df_out = df1.merge(df2_info, on='ID', how='left')
```

**Result**

```
print(df_out)

     ID    Name  Age                                                                                  Info
0  AB01  toyota   21  [{'ID': 'AB01', 'Type': 'C', 'Score': 87}, {'ID': 'AB01', 'Type': nan, 'Score': 98}]
1  AB02   honda   22                                                                                   NaN
```

For reference only, interim result of `df2_info`:

```
     ID                                                                                  Info
0  AB01  [{'ID': 'AB01', 'Type': 'C', 'Score': 87}, {'ID': 'AB01', 'Type': nan, 'Score': 98}]
1  AB03  [{'ID': 'AB03', 'Type': 'X', 'Score': 45}, {'ID': 'AB03', 'Type': 'S', 'Score': 82}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `merge`:

```
print(df1.merge(df2, on='ID', how='left').groupby(['ID', 'Name', 'Age']).apply(lambda x: a.to_dict('records') if (a:=x[['ID']].join(x.iloc[:, 3:])).dropna().any().any() else []).reset_index(name='Info'))
```

Output:

```
     ID    Name  Age                                               Info
0  AB01  toyota   21  [{'ID': 'AB01', 'Type': 'C', 'Score': 87.0}, {...
1  AB02   honda   22                                                 []
```